# Where to handle reCAPTCHA? In JavaScript or in PHP?

Tags: php, vue.js, recaptcha

My experience in web development is near to zero, but I found a [simple example](https://github.com/elephantbug/JsLib/tree/master/contact-form) of a contact form with reCAPTCHA and trying to figure out how to make it work on my WordPress site. There is the [live demo](https://test.developernote.com/JsLib/contact-form/).

Is it possible to implement 'submit' function in index.js in a way it checks the captcha, send the form data asynchronously and handle the response?

```
new Vue({
  // root node
  el: "#app",
  // the instance state
  //...
  methods: {
    // submit form handler
    submit: function() {
      this.submitted = true;
    },
  //..
});
```

If yes there can be a PHP script on the server side that handles the request, calls mail(...) and returns "OK", but it is not clear how to check the captcha in this case? Who checks it, JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: whenever I've used recaptcha I've always used both JS and PHP. JS validates on the client side but can be bypassed without a server-side check using PHP. There may be a method of implementing it securerly without the PHP side of things but I am not aware of how to do that.

Comment: @FergalAndrews what submit function should do to send the captcha result to PHP?

Comment: I've posted an answer below Alexey

Comment: Here is a page for implementing https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class method that I use. The argument ($gRecaptchaResponse) is what is returned by google when you submit the captcha using javascript

```
protected function validateGoogleRecaptcha($gRecaptchaResponse)
{

    $secretKey = $this->config['application']['captcha']['recaptcha']['secretKey'];
    $reCaptcha = new \ReCaptcha($secretKey);

    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $gRecaptchaResponse
    );

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: is it possible without reloading the page?

Comment: @Alexey - I have used the recaptcha with an ajax form submission. There are a few websites that give instructions. Example: https://developer.hyvor.com/php/validate-google-recaptcha-with-ajax-and-php